# PaintColor won't change on android Drawing app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-drawer

Hi everybady hope your are fine

i have a litle problem in my very basic Drawing android app
i have an Image Button to change PaintColor but the problem is :the Color is Change for just milisecond then it come back to the basic color witch define in the DrawingView class ,other problem is all the previeus Drawing Lines Change to the newColor and come back to the basic one
**this is my 2 classes it is very basic project**

```
DrawingView.kt
package com.wissewassim.kid_drawing_app

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class DrawingView (context : Context, attrs :AttributeSet) : View(context,attrs)  {
    private var mDrawPath : CustomPath? = null
    private var mCanvasBitmap : Bitmap? = null
    private var mDrawPaint : Paint? = null
    private var mCanvasPaint : Paint? = null
    private var mBrishSize : Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var color : Int = Color.CYAN
    private var canvas : Canvas? = null
    private val paths   = ArrayList<CustomPath>()

    init {
        setUpDrawing()
    }
    private fun setUpDrawing(){
        /** we give it  to drawPath to draw in the screen  */
        mDrawPaint = Paint()
        /**we use it to draw on the scren using the Paint that returnned from customPath.class */
        mDrawPath = CustomPath(color,mBrishSize)
        /**define the style and the color and the edges of the line of the draw (attributes) */
        mDrawPaint!!.color = color
        mDrawPaint!!.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mDrawPaint!!.strokeCap =  Paint.Cap.ROUND
        mDrawPaint!!.strokeJoin =  Paint.Join.ROUND
        /**we use it to draw the canvas on the view with PaintFlag
         * PaintFlag: how does this canvas render in the screen*/
        mCanvasPaint= Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        /**the size of the brush we use it to draw lines */
          mBrishSize = 20.toFloat()
    }
    /** put canvas it the view each time the screen size changed
     *  or an view was added to the hierarchy
     *  */
    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        canvas = Canvas(mCanvasBitmap!!)

    }

    /**هده الدالى تستدعي عند بدأ الرسم علي canvas*/

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        /**
         *           بقوم بالرسم باستخدام دالة ال canvas نمرر لها (  mCanvasPaint witch has the Attributes of the draw  ,الاحداصيات Y;الاحداصيات X,الكنفس التي سنرسم عليها )
         */

        canvas.drawBitmap(mCanvasBitmap!!,0f,0f,mCanvasPaint)
        //set mDrawPaint stroke and color using the old path colors to draw it again
        for (path in  paths){

            //initialize the stroke width using the object we created from customPath.class
            mDrawPaint!!.strokeWidth = path.brishThickness
            mDrawPath!!.color = path.color
            //
            canvas.drawPath(path,mDrawPaint!!)
        }
        //check if the drawPath was created using the inner class CustomPath
        if(!mDrawPath!!.isEmpty){
            //initialize the stroke width using the object we created from customPath.class
            mDrawPaint!!.strokeWidth = mDrawPath!!.brishThickness
            //initialize the draw color  using the object we created from customPath.class
            mDrawPaint!!.color = mDrawPath!!.color
            ///pass the drawpath and draw paint to the canvas to draw the path in the method draw path
            canvas.drawPath(mDrawPath!!,mDrawPaint!!)
        }
    }
    fun setBrushSize(newSize : Float){
        mBrishSize= TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,newSize,resources.displayMetrics)
        mDrawPaint!!.strokeWidth = mBrishSize
        mDrawPaint!!.color = color
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        val touchX = event?.x
        val touchY = event?.y
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

                mDrawPath!!.color = color
                mDrawPath!!.brishThickness = mBrishSize
                mDrawPath!!.reset()

                if (touchY != null) {
                    if (touchX != null) {
                        mDrawPath!!.moveTo(touchX, touchY)
                    }
                }

            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (touchY != null) {
                    if (touchX != null) {
                        mDrawPath!!.lineTo(touchX, touchY)
                    }
                }
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                paths.add(mDrawPath!!)
                mDrawPath = CustomPath(color, mBrishSize )

            }

            else -> return false
        }
        invalidate()
        return true



    }

    fun setpathColor(newColor : Int ){
        color = newColor
        mDrawPaint!!.color= color
    }

    /** inner class to create customPath that we use to draw using it */
    internal class CustomPath(var color:Int, var brishThickness : Float ): Path()

}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.wissewassim.kid_drawing_app

import android.app.Dialog
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnClickListener
import android.widget.ImageButton
import com.wissewassim.kid_drawing_app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var brushSize = 0.toFloat()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        //set the default brush size
        binding.drawingView.setBrushSize(20.toFloat())
        //change brush size when choose size in choosing brush size Dialog
          binding.ibBrushSizeChange.setOnClickListener{ brushSizeDialog() }
       binding.ibBrushColorRed.setOnClickListener(brushSizeDialog())
        binding.ibBrushColorGreen.setOnClickListener(brushSizeDialog())
        binding.ibBrushColorBlack.setOnClickListener(brushSizeDialog())
        binding.ibBrushColorBlue.setOnClickListener(brushSizeDialog())
        binding.ibBrushColorYellow.setOnClickListener(brushSizeDialog())
}
    private fun brushSizeDialog(){
        val brushDialog = Dialog(this)
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_brush_size)
        brushDialog.setTitle("set brush size :")

        val smallbrush = brushDialog.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ib_small_brush_size)
        val mudiumbrush = brushDialog.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ib_meduim_brush_size)
        val largebrush = brushDialog.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ib_large_brush_size)
        smallbrush.setOnClickListener{
            brushSize = 20.toFloat()
            binding.drawingView.setBrushSize(brushSize)
            brushDialog.dismiss()

        }
        mudiumbrush.setOnClickListener{
            brushSize = 30.toFloat()
            binding.drawingView.setBrushSize(brushSize)
            brushDialog.dismiss()

        }
        largebrush.setOnClickListener{
            brushSize = 40.toFloat()
            binding.drawingView.setBrushSize(brushSize)
            brushDialog.dismiss()

        }
    brushDialog.show()

    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
       when(v?.id){
           binding.ibBrushColorRed.id->{
               binding.drawingView.setpathColor(Color.RED)
           }
               binding.ibBrushColorBlack.id->{
               binding.drawingView.setpathColor(Color.BLACK)
           }
               binding.ibBrushColorYellow.id->{
               binding.drawingView.setpathColor(Color.YELLOW)
           }
               binding.ibBrushColorGreen.id->{
               binding.drawingView.setpathColor(Color.GREEN)
           }
               binding.ibBrushColorBlue.id->{
               binding.drawingView.setpathColor(Color.BLUE)
           }
       }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `DrawingView` class with this :

```
class DrawingView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {
    private var mDrawPath: CustomPath? = null
    private var mCanvasBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    private var mDrawPaint: Paint? = null
    private var mCanvasPaint: Paint? = null
    private var mBrishSize: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var color: Int = Color.CYAN
    private var canvas: Canvas? = null
    private val paths = ArrayList<CustomPath>()
    private val pathColorList = ArrayList<Pair<CustomPath, Int>>()


    init {
        setUpDrawing()
    }

    private fun setUpDrawing() {
        /** we give it  to drawPath to draw in the screen  */
        mDrawPaint = Paint()
        /**we use it to draw on the scren using the Paint that returnned from customPath.class */
        mDrawPath = CustomPath(color, mBrishSize)
        /**define the style and the color and the edges of the line of the draw (attributes) */
        mDrawPaint!!.color = color
        mDrawPaint!!.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mDrawPaint!!.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        mDrawPaint!!.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        /**we use it to draw the canvas on the view with PaintFlag
         * PaintFlag: how does this canvas render in the screen*/
        mCanvasPaint = Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        /**the size of the brush we use it to draw lines */
        mBrishSize = 20.toFloat()
    }

    /** put canvas it the view each time the screen size changed
     *  or an view was added to the hierarchy
     *  */
    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        canvas = Canvas(mCanvasBitmap!!)

    }

    /**هده الدالى تستدعي عند بدأ الرسم علي canvas*/

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawBitmap(mCanvasBitmap!!, 0f, 0f, mCanvasPaint)
        for ((path, color) in pathColorList) {
            mDrawPaint!!.strokeWidth = path.brishThickness
            mDrawPaint!!.color = color
            canvas.drawPath(path, mDrawPaint!!)
        }
        if (!mDrawPath!!.isEmpty) {
            mDrawPaint!!.strokeWidth = mDrawPath!!.brishThickness
            mDrawPaint!!.color = mDrawPath!!.color
            canvas.drawPath(mDrawPath!!, mDrawPaint!!)
        }
    }

    fun setBrushSize(newSize: Float) {
        mBrishSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            newSize,
            resources.displayMetrics
        )
        mDrawPaint!!.strokeWidth = mBrishSize
        mDrawPaint!!.color = color
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        val touchX = event?.x
        val touchY = event?.y
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

                mDrawPath!!.color = color
                mDrawPath!!.brishThickness = mBrishSize
                mDrawPath!!.reset()

                if (touchY != null) {
                    if (touchX != null) {
                        mDrawPath!!.moveTo(touchX, touchY)
                    }
                }

            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (touchY != null) {
                    if (touchX != null) {
                        mDrawPath!!.lineTo(touchX, touchY)
                    }
                }
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                paths.add(mDrawPath!!)
                mDrawPath = CustomPath(color, mBrishSize)

            }

            else -> return false
        }
        invalidate()
        return true


    }

    fun setpathColor(newColor: Int) {
        color = newColor
        mDrawPaint!!.color = color
        val pair = Pair(mDrawPath!!, newColor)
        pathColorList.add(pair)
    }

    /** inner class to create customPath that we use to draw using it */
    internal class CustomPath(var color: Int, var brishThickness: Float) : Path()

}
```

Comment: this not work when i write for the fist time the app open any line draw gone
when i choose an other color is only save the fist line but the other is gone and every other color it save only the first line draw with it and the color is changed in all of the lines was drawed before
please search where the problem is and tell me

Comment: @منوعات I've tested and everything seems to work fine with me, did you modify or added some code to it ? If yes, update your question with the new code